# Computing an map of minimum distance to a number of points

Tags: python, algorithm, math, numpy, computational-geometry

Given a list of points `obstacles` (given as a list of `row, column` matrix coordinates, an ndarray of shape `(n, 2)`), return a map of size `size` (where `size` is the shape of the 2D NumPy array) in which the value of `r, c` is the Euclidean distance to the closest "obstacle."

```
def gen_distgrid(size, obstacles):
    n_obstacles = obstacles.shape[0]
    distgrids = np.zeros((n_obstacles + 4, size[0], size[1]))
    for layer in range(n_obstacles):
        for i in range(size[0]):
            for j in range(size[1]):
                distgrids[layer, i, j] = np.linalg.norm(obstacles[layer,:] - [i,j])
    for i in range(size[0]):
            for j in range(size[1]):
                distgrids[n_obstacles + 0, i, j] = i
                distgrids[n_obstacles + 1, i, j] = (size[0] - i)
                distgrids[n_obstacles + 2, i, j] = j
                distgrids[n_obstacles + 3, i, j] = (size[1] - j)
    distgrid = np.min(distgrids, axis=0)
    return distgrid
```

My method is really slow, and I feel like there should be a better one.

Comment: Sorry, what are `r` and `c`?

Comment: @mgilson: row and column, or you can say `i, j`.

Comment: so, for each obstacle, you want to know which other obstacle is the closest?

Comment: @mgilson: no, for every point in the grid.

Comment: Sorry, still not getting it -- What's the grid?  I don't see much mention of it in the question, but there is some code which appears to generate a grid and do something with it ....

Comment: @mgilson: you're returning `distgrid`, which is of size `size`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [a KD-tree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) from SciPy. It has a very easy distance function.

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree
def gen_distgrid(obstacles):
    n_obstacles = obstacles.shape[0]
    obstacles = np.vstack((obstacles, [0,0], [0, size[1] - 1], [size[0] - 1, 0], [size[0] - 1, size[1] - 1]))

    distgrid = np.zeros((size[0], size[1]))
    obs_tree = KDTree(data=obstacles)

    i_v = np.arange(size[0])
    j_v = np.arange(size[1])

    coordmat = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(i_v, j_v, indexing='ij'))
    obs_dists, obs_locs = obs_tree.query(coordmat)

    top_dists = np.repeat(i_v, size[1]).reshape(size)
    bottom_dists = np.repeat(size[0] - i_v, size[1]).reshape(size)
    left_dists = np.repeat(j_v, size[0]).reshape(np.transpose(size)).T
    right_dists = np.repeat(size[1] - j_v, size[0]).reshape(np.transpose(size)).T

    dists = np.min([obs_dists, top_dists, bottom_dists, left_dists, right_dists], axis=0)
    return dists
```